# Using url parameters, I am trying to create a gallery of thumbnails that coorespond into my table

Tags: php, glob

I am trying to create some a gallery in my page using this html:

```
<tr>
  <th> Sunday</th>
  <th> Monday</th>
  <th> Tuesday</th>
  <th> Wednesday</th>
  <th> Thursday</th>
  <th> Friday</th>
  <th> Saturday</th>
</tr>


<tr>
  <td><img src="pics_index.php?size=110&index=0"></td>
  <td><img src="pics_index.php?size=110&index=1"></td>
  <td><img src="pics_index.php?size=110&index=2"></td>
  <td><img src="pics_index.php?size=110&index=3"></td>
  <td><img src="pics_index.php?size=110&index=4"></td>
  <td><img src="pics_index.php?size=110&index=5"></td>
  <td><img src="pics_index.php?size=110&index=6"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I am going to glob the 7 images and then create an array  of the image names it contains:

```
    <?php

include('pics_reduce_lib.php');

$images = array("pics_daily/degas.jpg","pics_daily/manet.jpg","pics_daily/monet.jpg","pics_daily/renoir.jpg","pics_daily/rousseau$
for ($index=0;$index=<7;++$i)
}
$pics = glob("pics_daily/*.{gif,jpg,png}",GLOB_BRACE);
$filename = $pics[$images];
$newWidth = $_GET["size"];
$contents = resizeToVariable($filename);  

header("Content-type: $type");
print $contents;


?>
```

resizeToVariable is my image resize program.

Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong? it cannot display. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
$images = array("test1.jpg","test1.jpg","test1.jpg","test1.jpg","test1.jpg","test1.jpg");
$filename = $images[$_GET['index']];
```